# When building HTTP API with Rails 3.2, should I disable front end things such as .js files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When building HTTP API which respond only JSON format with Rails 3.2, should I turn off things like Asset Pipeline and javascript files?

If so, how to do it correctly instead of manually deleting which sounds dirty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a good idea if you're only serving up the api, here's how:

```
rails new appname --skip-sprockets
```

For an existing application, in your application.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```